# mysql primary key,is it a hash index or b-tree?

Tags: mysql, database

the primary key is automaticlly created and has a index type "primary". is it a hash or b-tree.

cos b-tree is rangeable and hash is not.

so, if the "primary" is b-tree then I can query it with a range selection.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Nonsense, of course it matters. It makes all the difference in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're using the `MEMORY` access method, your MySQL indexes are organized as BTREEs and can be suitable for range scan queries.